# RavenDB in MVC is not saving data to the database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ravendb

Below are the steps that I've done to use RavenDB in client/server mode (not embedded) for my ASP.Net MVC application. Although I am following exactly the steps but the results are not as expected. Please correct me if there's any mistakes made.

1. Install RavenDB.Client & RavenDB.Server via Nuget.
2. Go to Packages folder, start Raven.Server.exe to get the service running
3. Open http://localhost:8080/ in browser, RavenStudio is up.
4. Created a database, say named as "testdb"
5. I have a RestaurantModel.cs.

   ```
   internal class RestaurantModel{
     public string ResName { get; set; }
     public string ResAddress { get; set; }
     public string ResCity { get; set; }
     public string ResState { get; set; }
     public int ResPostcode { get; set; }
     public string ResPhoneNum { get; set; }
   }
   ```
6. In my controller, I've initialized the document store, as well as opening the session.

   ```
   public ActionResult Index()
   {
       using (var store = new DocumentStore
       {
           Url = "http://localhost:8080/",
           DefaultDatabase = "testdb"
       })
       {
           store.Initialize();

           using (var session = store.OpenSession())
           {
               session.Store(new RestaurantModel
               {
                   ResName = "TestName",
                   ResAddress = "Test Address",
                   ResCity = "TestCity",
                   ResState = "TestState",
                   ResPostcode = 82910,
                   ResPhoneNum = "02-28937481"
               });

               session.SaveChanges();

           }
       }

           return View();
   }
   ```
7. Build the solution. Refresh localhost:8080, data is still not inserted.
8. I have no idea what am I doing wrong although I'm following exactly all the tutorials I've gone through. So many attempts using different ways but still to no avail.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Tried hitting debug, it opens localhost:33062, but then it shows me server error as shown in below.

[image]

## # To be more specific #

1. I have a RestaurantModel.cs

   ```
   internal class RestaurantModel
   {
     public string ResName { get; set; }
     public string ResAddress { get; set; }
     public string ResCity { get; set; }
     public string ResState { get; set; }
     public int ResPostcode { get; set; }
     public string ResPhoneNum { get; set; }
   }
   ```
2. I have a AdminController

   ```
   using FYP2.Models;
   using Raven.Client.Document;
   using System;
   using System.Collections.Generic;
   using System.Linq;
   using System.Web;
   using System.Web.Mvc;

   namespace FYP2.Controllers
   {
   public class AdminController : Controller
   {
       // GET: Admin
       public ActionResult Index()
       {
           using (var store = new DocumentStore
           {
               Url = "http://localhost:8080/",
               DefaultDatabase = "foodfurydb"
           })
           {
               store.Initialize();

               using (var session = store.OpenSession())
               {
                   session.Store(new RestaurantModel
                   {
                       ResName = "Boxer Republic",
                       ResAddress = "NO 2A-G, Jalan BK 5A/2C",
                       ResCity = "Puchong",
                       ResState = "Selangor",
                       ResPostcode = 47180,
                       ResPhoneNum = "03-80748088"
                   });

                   session.SaveChanges();

               }
           }

               return View();
       }

       public ActionResult AdminLogin()
       {
           return View();
       }

       public ActionResult AddRestaurant()
       {
           return View();
       }

       public ActionResult ManageFoodMenu()
       {
           return View();
       }

       public ActionResult ManageOrder()
       {
           return View();
       }

       public ActionResult ManageReservation()
       {
           return View();
       }

   }
   }
   ```
3. I have Admin View, consist of

```
AddRestaurant, AdminLogin, ManageFoodMenu, ManageOrder, ManageReservation
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really don't know what can cause this problem. Just one question, you just compiled the project or you called your action `domain:port/yourcontroller/index`?

I've created a mvc project and copied your code:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    internal class RestaurantModel
    {
        public string ResName { get; set; }
        public string ResAddress { get; set; }
        public string ResCity { get; set; }
        public string ResState { get; set; }
        public int ResPostcode { get; set; }
        public string ResPhoneNum { get; set; }
    }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        using (var store = new DocumentStore
        {
            Url = "http://locaslhost:8080/",
            DefaultDatabase = "testdb"
        })
        {
            store.Initialize();

            using (var session = store.OpenSession())
            {
                session.Store(new RestaurantModel
                {
                    ResName = "TestName",
                    ResAddress = "Test Address",
                    ResCity = "TestCity",
                    ResState = "TestState",
                    ResPostcode = 82910,
                    ResPhoneNum = "02-28937481"
                });

                session.SaveChanges();

            }
        }

        return View();
    }
}
```

When I accessed the path `http://localhost:50791/` which corresponds to my `HomeController/Index`, everything went as expected:

[image]

Can you give more details about you are trying to do?

Comment: the method `public ActionResult Index() {}` is an `Action` from a `Controller` right? It means that your project will respond to that route. Try this: Hit debug on your project. It will start your mvc application. Then, if you are not in HomeController, add /NameOfYouControllerWithoutController. It will create your database and add the data!

Comment: I've tried debugging. It then opens up localhost:33062 but showing server error. I wonder what's wrong?

Comment: What type of project you have created?

Comment: ASP.NET MVC. I've added extra information on what I have in my project above. Anyway, I tried to create a fresh and clean project using MVC as well and this time it works! I have no idea what gone wrong.